# JavaFx - When selecting a text field, text field changes its scale and it effects the other items in flowpane. How to get rid of it

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

There is group of items (three `textfield` and a `button`). One of the textfields is in an other group (to put an mouse transparent image on it). When this textfield is selected the parent group get bigger for a fex pixels and all of the flowpane items get shifted. How can i get rid of this beheivor.

```
            <Group layoutX="123.0" layoutY="74.0">
               <children>
                  <FlowPane prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="283.0">
                     <children>
                        <Group>
                           <children>
                              <TextField prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="72.0" />
                           </children>
                        </Group>
                        <TextField prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="82.0" />
                        <TextField prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="76.0" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
                     </children>
                  </FlowPane>
               </children>
            </Group>
```

Seen here:

[image: visualization]

<sub>Note: Code and gif created to demonstrate the problem.</sub>

I want textfield to not change its parents sizes even his size changes. Or any other solution.

Comment: Don't hard-code sizes or positions. You almost certainly don't want a `Group` here. If you want these controls to stay in a single horizontal line, use a `HBox`, not a `FlowPane`. Create and post a [mre] if those hints don't fix the issue.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `FlowPane`?

Comment: @James_D As i mentioned above the reaseon i use the textfield in a `group` is you can not put things on top of each other if components are in some kind of container (pane/box) (Gridpane might work with increasing row span). I use this to put an image on top of textfield. If you do have advise on this matter, i am open to change it.

Comment: @SedJ601 There are more to these components in the real situation. It wouldnt harm to use a gridpane with tons of rows and columns but flowpane looks a bit more suitable for the situation. If things do not work out with flowpane i can give up and use something else :(

Comment: *"you can not put things on top of each other if components are in some kind of container (pane/box)"* -> that is wrong.  `StackPane` is made to stack nodes on top of one another.  A `Pane` has the same layout functionality as a `Group` in terms of `Node` placement.  And you can set any the `managed` property of any node to unmanaged in any pane type, then manually place the node where-ever you want.  All these methods use the [painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm).

Comment: @jewelsea i should have been said _"i can not put things on top each other if ..."_ :) Thanks that solves the expending borders issue too. Turns out i didnt know the existence of `StackPane` and how useful it is in this situation. If you can write it as an answer i can mark it. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>@jewelsea 's comment solves the problem.</sub>

Using a `StackPane` to put components on top each other doesn't disturb the layout like using `Group` container does.

<sub>*So we can say; To put two components on top of each other use `StackPane` in fxml.*</sub>

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: I still don't get why you are using `FlowPane`. If you don't want the behavior you got originally, you should not use `FlowPane`. You said there will be more nodes added. If that's the case, you still run the risk of having the same behavior happening again.